# How to delete everything in a folder except one or two folders that I want to retain?

Tags: python

I have folder "Folder1" that contains files and folders such as "file1", "file2" "Folder11" "Folder12" "Folder13" etc. I want to retain only "Folder11" & "Folder12" and delete rest of the things. I need help to write python script for the same.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far for the same

Comment: Get list of all folders. Filter out ones to keep then delete the others. You should find answers to all those steps on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`os module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to loop through every item and folder in your directory and delete them. You could also define a list with specific items (like your folder names) to prevent them from being deleted. Keep in mind that if you want to keep files from being removed, you also have to add their format (like ".txt" for a text file).

As usual, be careful when deleting files. Maybe you want to add a check before the `os.remove()` or maybe replace it with a print statement first (`print(item)`) so that you see what is being removed.

```
import os  # Import the os module

working_directory = r"C:\Users\Vishwesh\Folder1"

retain = ["Folder11", "Folder12", "file1.txt", "file2.txt"]

os.chdir(working_directory)  # Change directory to your folder

# Loop through everything in folder in current working directory
for item in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if item not in retain:  # If it isn't in the list for retaining
        os.remove(item)  # Remove the item
```